# Fibrinous inflammation, exudate and scarring in monotonous movements and ageing

Tags: physiology, senescence, pathogenesis, adaptation

I have palpated many hard organs during my work and studies.
I have seen many young and old people who have hard organs, like very hard shoulder - very common.
I have interviewed some of them, some points

- only one type of weight lifting
- no running
- no stretching
- no stretching before training
- no stretching after training
- not age dependent only - very old can be healthy
- dynamical movement dependent

There are two mechanisms of fibrinous inflammation

- trigger the release of fibrinogen
- trigger release of fibrinogen-to-fibrin reaction

which both result in the production fibrin in the interstitium:

[image]

The area may also be mixed with serous so two variations of fibrinous inflammation

- serofibrinous
- fibrinous.

I am interested in the mechanism that leads to this hard tissue throughout the organ.
This raised to me an idea about Fibrinous inflammation in the shoulder.
Robbins say that if the exudate cannot be sucked out, it leads to scarring.
I think this is what is making the organ feel hard.

**What is the pathogenesis in such monotonous movements without stretching?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would now say that the hardening is just **local acute venous congestion** if in the short term.
Without stretching after practice, it just takes more days to recover.
So lymphatic drainage is the one which helps the muscle get its needs and nutrients.

If this happens during years, it is difficult to say what is the causal factor.
It depends on many factors. 
One key factor is how well the lymphatic circulation can recover the body back.
So genomics of the patient comes in the picture.
Many other factors too like anatomical structure of chest.
Then, depending on these factors and other pathological processes may happen many processes like

- accumulation of fibrinoid
- accumulation of calcium deposits
- shorter diffuse distances
- smaller total area of cells

which are some adaptation processes to the ageing (also of prolonged monotonous weight lifting).
They can lead to

- acute lymphangitis (reddening of the skin)
- Chronic lymphangitis
- Chronic Granulomatous Lymphadenitis (fibrosis happening between muscles and connection points - not in all cases granulomatous - rare only)
- lymphadenopathy (very, very late - after many years)

during ageing (adaptation).

Better question would probably be: **what are processes happening during ageing?**
And then cover pathologies of ageing separately and also the physiological processes on the weight lifting separately.